# Angular Outside Subscribe Value Null

Tags: angular, typescript, service

I work on a project that basically calls service method via a mediate class which is called ServiceHandler. In the component the console output of the result variable is `undefined`.
Is there any solution to solve this problem?

**Component**

```
this.entityServiceHandler.saveEntityWithCondition(entity).subscribe(data => { this.result = data});

console.log(this.result);
```

**ServiceHandler**

```
public saveEntityWithCondition(entity): Observable<Entity>{
    var subject = new Subject<any>();

    this.subscriptions.push(
      forkJoin({
        conditionTrue: this.entityService.isConditionTrue(entity.property)
      }).subscribe(({ conditionTrue }) => {
   
        if (conditionTrue) {
        
            this.entityService.save(entity).subscribe(
              (response: Entity) => {
                subject.next(response);
                
              },
              (errorResponse: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                
              }
            )
        }
      },
      err => {},
      () => {
      }));

    return subject.asObservable();

}
```

**Service**

```
public save(item: Entity) : Observable<Entity>{

  public save(item: Entity): Observable<Entity> {   
      return this.httpClient.post<Entity>(`path`, item).pipe(catchError((err) => this.handleAndThrowError(err)));
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you see `undefined` is that you are mixing synchronous and asynchronous code and this often leads to problems. Just move the `console.log` inside the `subscribe` and it should be OK.

```typescript
// Asynchronous code - takes some time to finalize
this.entityServiceHandler.saveEntityWithCondition(entity).subscribe(data => {
  this.result = data;
  console.log(this.resul) // This'll be shown
});

// Synchronous code - happens just after calling previous, doesn't wait for it
// to finish. This means, result is undefined
console.log(this.result);
```

**EDIT:**
I took a liberty and simplified your code a bit. You are doing lots of unnecessary things, like `forkJoin` for just one observable. Or pushing a subscription to an Array, likely to close it later, but it's not needed when you refcator your code a bit.

```
import { filter, switchMap, catchError, EMPTY } from 'rxjs';

public saveEntityWithCondition(entity): Observable<Entity> {
  // No need to forkJoin, just call the function and pipe it
  return this.entityService.isConditionTrue(entity.property).pipe(
    // This makes sure that conditionTrue is true indeed
    filter(conditionTrue => conditionTrue),
    // Then use switchMap to call the entity service and perform save
    switchMap(() => this.entityService.save(entity)),
    // And use catchError to handle possible issues
    catchError(error => {
      // handle error in some way - i.e. log it or something;
      return EMPTY; 
    })
  );

}
```

You don't need `subject` anymore because you are returning the `Observable<Entity>` directly.

You also don't need to push the `Subscription` to an array, because thanks to the HttpClient you are using and the `switchMap` operator included, it will handle `unsubcribe` automatically, when `save` is finished.